# Deleting files and folders in windows

Tags: windows-7

I am having trouble with deleting some folders in windows 7.

The problem that it says is that the content is not present here when I try to delete the folder. So I guess that its only a visual folder as the size of all of it is 0 Kb.

I have also tried to use `unlocker` software but since there is no actual data present it fails.

Is there some hack or method that would remove these folders?

Comment: Did you restart your machine and check again?

Comment: Yup i did ... and no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, this happens, when a application is pointer inside the folder, whether or not, the application is accessing a file inside it.

Try closing all the applications(if they can be closed) and try deleting it again. Or do a quick restart and delete it afterwards. Or Even if you can't delete it, then, it must either be a virus or a bad sector in your hard disk. For the earlier, scan and remove using a AV, for the later, try to fix the sector or format the drive after backing up the data.

Answer (score 0):

try doing a quick scan disk first (it might fix it)

if that doesn't do anything, try booting with something like hiren's boot cd or some linux live cd distribution and delete it from there

but my guess is that a scan disk will fix it

Comment: even scan disk is not working ... as in i issue the scan and fix from the tools property and it says that it needs to restart to check for bad sectors ... when I do that it gets automatically cancelled without me pressing any key....I don't know what to do..